# How to check front Cam ID? also getting captured image is mirror image from front camera.

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I am trying to use default camera with Intent for both image and video capture.
when i turn to front camera and capture the image or video preview (captured image or video ) is inverted   . So now I want to put **preScale** in **frontCamera**.   But didn't know where to find **Camera ID in default Camera**.!!

**Note : this is not Custom Camera.!!**

**Problem is :  Captured Image from Front camera getting image is mirror image.  Look into it if there any problem ?    I didnt get ! Thx**

**Even stored captured image in SDCard also mirror image!  Now how to preScale or any other idea to correct iT??**

Help!

```
 photo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            captureImage();


        }
    });
```

CatureImage method

```
private void captureImage() {

    Context context = this;
    PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    if (packageManager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA) == false
            && packageManager
            .hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_ANY) == false) {
        Toast.makeText(CameraRolling2.this, "camera not available'",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent
            .resolveActivity(CameraRolling2.this.getPackageManager()) != null) {
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
            Toast.makeText(CameraRolling2.this, "Error connecting camera",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                    Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent,
                    CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);

            showImg.setImageBitmap(null);
        }
    }
}


@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
            .format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = Environment
            .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

    File image = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", storageDir);

    mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();

    Log.v("createImageFile", "" + mCurrentPhotoPath);
    return image;
}
```

and My Activity Result

```
 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE
            && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

        File imgFile = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
        if (imgFile.exists()) {

            BitmapFactory.Options bitmap_options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            bitmap_options.inSampleSize = 4;
            bitmap_options.outHeight = 200;
            bitmap_options.outWidth = 200;

            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(
                    imgFile.getAbsolutePath(), bitmap_options);
            showImg.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
            if (showImg.getDrawable() == null) {
                Log.e("IMAGEVIEW", "NULL IMAGE");
                imageflag = false;
            } else {
                Log.e("IMAGEVIEW", "IMAGE VIEW UPDATED");
                imageflag = true;
            }

        }
    }
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
        Toast.makeText(CameraRolling2.this, "Camera option canceled",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        imageflag = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to use default camera with Intent for both image and video capture

There is no single "default camera with Intent" in Android. There are thousands of Android device models. These ship with hundreds of different "default camera with Intent" apps. Users can install other "default camera with Intent" apps from the Play Store or other places. Any one of those apps could be what the user chooses to use to take the picture (`ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`) or record the video (`ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE`).

> when i turn to front camera and capture the image or video preview (captured image or video ) is inverted

I am going to guess that by "inverted", you mean "rotated".

There are hundreds of different possible camera apps. Many will save the image or video with metadata that tells the viewer app to rotate the image (e.g., JPEG photos might have an orientation EXIF header). Some will not, electing to rotate the content themselves.

Also, the images or videos from any camera (front-facing, rear-facing, external) could be rotated.

Hence, you should not be assuming that the rotation is tied to the particular camera that the user used. Instead, examine the actual content and react accordingly. [This sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Camera/EXIFRotater) demonstrates this for rotating a JPEG image, using a couple of different techniques.

> So now I want to put preScale in frontCamera.

You cannot control this.

> But didn't know where to find Camera ID in default Camera.!!

You cannot control this.

Comment: inverted means getting mirror  image

Comment: @HarshBhavsar: Regardless, you have no means of forcing a third-party camera app to use a particular hardware camera (front-facing/rear-facing/etc.). You have no means of detecting which camera was used. You have no means of determining if the user, inside the camera app, flipped the image, cropped it, or otherwise, affected the image's outcome.

Comment: @HarshBhavsar: You are welcome to use the camera APIs directly, so you have complete control over the user experience. Right now, you are delegating that work to a third-party camera app. That means what the pictures and videos look like is up to the authors of that app, plus the user.

Comment: yea. got it ! but  i dont know why from front camera (default ) captured image and video getting mirror image/videos... !!